# How to convert string into datetime

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

When i click the gridview column, that selected column items should appear in the datetime picker

GridView Column value is string, datetime picker datatype is datetime

Code

```
 Private Sub gridview1_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles gridview1.CellContentDoubleClick
        Dim i As Integer
        i = gridview1.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim dt As String = gridview1.Item(1, i).Value
        datetimepicker1.value = CDate(dt)
 End Sub
```

When i clicked the gridview column, it is showing error as "Conversion from string "25/09/2011" to type 'Date' is not valid"

How to solve the above problem

Need VB.Net Code Help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which date format to expect in advance, use DateTime.ParseExact, e.g.:

```
datetimepicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related to locale settings in that the CDATE() function expects date values to be provided in the following format: MM/DD/YYYY (MM = Month, DD = Day, YYYY = Year).  This means the code fails in the UK which is DD/MM/YYYY.  Passing 25/09/2011 is translated to:

- Month = 25
- Day = 09
- Year = 2011

If the value you're using is a string you'll need to parse the string value to extract the correct values before passing it to the CDate() function:

```
Private Sub gridview1_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles holidaygrid.CellContentDoubleClick

    textbox1.Text = DateTime.ParseExact( _
        gridview1.Item(1, gridview1.CurrentRow.Index).Value, _
            "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()

 End Sub
```